# how to make expandable stack of cards in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm learning Flutter and I'm trying to create a stack of cards that can be expandable like a picture below but I couldn't find similar project out there for me to learn so can anybody help me how I can I achieve this in Flutter.

Card will be expand when user click "show more" and collapsed back after clicking "show less"

Answer (score 0):

you can do this manually but i think it's easier with packages so here are some packages that can help you achieve your goal:

for stack of card:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tindercard ,
https://pub.dev/packages/tinder_card

for card expansions:
https://pub.dev/packages/slimy_card ,
https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_card

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AnimatedPositioned() widget.

Here is the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html)

All you need is to create a list of card's states (opened, closed), and whether Card is tapped, change State.

Depending on Card state, change position in AnimatedPositioned() widget.
Also, this could be done with AnimatedContainer() instead of AnimatedPositioned()

Link to the AnimatedContainer() [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html)